# Is it bad practice to create arbitrary sql tables?

Tags: sql

What I'm asking is something along the lines of say I had user data to store and each user would have a list of items associated with them.

My first idea would be to make another table such as `$userid$_list` with the list in columns, for each user. That seems like bad practice so my other idea was to store a json formatted list in another column in the `users` table. Is the first one bad practice

---

I figured it was unnecessary but here's specifically what I'm trying to do, I'm making a bot for discord ([discord.gg](http://discord.gg)) and what I'm doing right now is making a new database file for each server with a bunch of tables.

Aside from more damage being done if there's data corruption, I was wondering if it would be acceptable for me to rather than have tables such as `warns`, `bans`, `kicks`, `custom_commands`, etc, I would have one database with `serverid_warns`, `serverid_bans`, `serverid_kicks`, and `serverid_custom_commands`.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to associate **users** to **items**.

For that, what you're looking for is known as a [**bridging table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) (or associative entity), which has a **[many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))** relationship. Have one table for **`users`**, and one table for **`items`**. Then build a third table as a bridging table to associate the IDs in each table to one another by using [**foreign keys**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of the ID field in each of the other two tables.

For example, this is the table `users`:

```
 ID  |  User
==== | ======
  1  |   Bob
  2  |   Jim
```

And this is the `items` table:

```
 ID  |   Item
==== | ========
  1  |   Sword
  2  |  Shield
```

For the purposes of my example, Bob owns a sword, and Jim owns both a sword and a shield.

As such, the bridging table would look like this:

```
 ID  |  UserID  | ItemID
==== | ======== | ======
  1  |    1     |   1
  2  |    2     |   1
  2  |    2     |   2
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I had thought of this but I was just thinking about sorting and that it would take a long time if all entries were in one table to get all items for one user but I guess it probably wouldn't be too bad, thanks!

Comment: Rows have **no order**. You simply extract the data that you want, and then sort the extracted data. Also, creating one bridging table will indeed have a few rows, though the number of rows would theoretically be identical to the number of rows in creating a table for each user. This is a much 'cleaner' approach, and also allows for easy association between multiple users.